# Windows Vista - behavior with RAM minimum

Tags: windows, windows-vista, virtualbox

I am considering creating a Vista install, in VirtualBox, in a minimum configuration.

The Microsoft pages seem consistent on the most important points:

1. 1 GB of system memory
2. 40 GB hard drive with at least 15 GB of available space
3. 128 MB of graphics memory (minimum)

In my experience sometimes these recommendations are accurate. (For example, I have a Windows XP in VirtualBox that generally behaves well running in the stated minimum). If anyone has some practical experience (especially the type that could save me hours of pain), please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be quite enough. I used it with only 1gb memory, its not bad, but you should set the theme to Windows Classic, remove un-needed applications through Programs and Features (or its "Add or Remove.." there?), disable services you don't need (can easily find howtos around the net.)

That will do the job I guess for you too.

(Basically it all matters what you want to do there. Like if you want to run a demanding application, then 1gb won't do it.)

Comment: Good tips, Shiki. I've found bumping it to 2GB is necessary when I want to run something like Visual Studio or SQL Server, but 1GB is enough for most anything else.